# OpenGL ES 1.1 strange lighting problems

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-lighting

I am examining an interesting problem I'm facing with OpenGL lighting on Android. I'm working on a 3D Viewer where you can add and manipulate 3D objects. You can also set a light with different attributes. The problem I was facing with my Viewer was that the highlight on the 3D objects from the light (it is a point light) behaved strangely. If the light source was in the exact same point as the camera, the highlight would move in the opposite direction you would expect. (So if you move the object to the left, the highlight moves to the leftedge of the object as well, instead of the right, which is what I was expecting.)

[image: The highlight is on the bottom left whereas i'd expect it to be on the right side]

So to further narrow the problem down I've created a small sample application that only renders a square and then I rotate that square around the camera position (the origin), which is also where the light is placed. This should result in all squares facing the camera directly, so that they would be completely highlighted. The result though looked like that:

[image: Lighting]

Can it be that these artifacts appear because of the distortion you get on the border due to the projection?

In the first image the distance between the sphere and the camera is about 20 units and the size of the sphere is about 2. If I move the light closer to the object the highlight looks a lot better, in the way I'm expecting it. 
In the second image the radius in which the squares are located is 25 units.
I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 (since I was struggling to get it to work with shaders in ES 2.0) on Android 3.1

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Setting the camera
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, -1f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(5f * i, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
        draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    setMaterial(gl);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

    // Enable the vertex and normal state
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mNormalBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndexBuffer.capacity(), GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

}

// Setting the light
private void drawLights(GL10 gl) {
    // Point Light
    float[] position = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    float[] diffuse = { .6f, .6f, .6f, 1f };
    float[] specular = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    float[] ambient = { .2f, .2f, .2f, 1 };

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
}

private void setMaterial(GL10 gl) {
    float shininess = 30;
    float[] ambient = { 0, 0, .3f, 1 };
    float[] diffuse = { 0, 0, .7f, 1 };
    float[] specular = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specular, 0);
    gl.glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shininess);
}
```

I'm setting the light in the beginning, when the activity is started (in onSurfaceCreated) and the material everytime I draw a square.

Comment: It would be a great help to see the fragment shader code you are using to shade the objects, and where its parameters are coming from.

Comment: Since I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 in both examples I'm not using shaders. ES 1.1 uses a fixed function pipeline. I'm going to update the post with a bit of code where I pass the parameters to OpenGL though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect in your second example (with the squares) is rather due to the default non-local viewer that OpenGL uses. By default the eye-space view vector (the vector from vertex to camera, used for the specular highlight computation) is just taken to be the (0, 0, 1)-vector, instead of the normalized vertex position. This approximation is only correct if the vertex is in the middle of the screen, but gets more and more incorrect the farther you move to the boundary of the srceen.

To change this and let OpenGL use the real vector from the vertex to the camera, just use the [`glLightModel`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLightModel.xml) function, especially

```
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
```

I'm not sure if this is also the cause for your first problem (with the sphere), but maybe, just try it.

**EDIT:** It seems you cannot use `GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER` in OpenGL ES. In this case there is no way around this problem, except switching to OpenGL ES 2.0 and doing all lighting computations yourself, of course.

Comment: This is exactly what we thought after some discussion and we realized it as well that it's not available in OpenGL ES. It's not really a big deal since in the actual application I will use OpenGL ES 2.0. I just wanted to have a comparison with how it renders the light with a fixed pipeline because with OpenGL ES 2.0 I encountered some strange situations. But in that case ES 1.1 doesn't really help me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: BTW we tried it as well on a Windows machine with OpenGL (not ES) and that was exactly where the problem was. Once we changed the LightModel it looked correct. Just for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your light is probably moving when you're moving your object.

Take a look at this answer http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm#ligh0050

Comment: In his current setup the light will always be positioned at the camera, which seems exactly what he wants, given his question text.